# Extend window variablein angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I had a angular project in angular 8 that I decided to update to angular 9. Everything looks ok, but I have a compilation problem.

I had a `global.d.ts` in the src folder of my project that had some type for libraries that are declared in the global scope :

```
import * as Cesium from "cesium";
import * as Hls from "hls.js";

declare global {
  var Cesium: typeof Cesium;
  var Hls: typeof Hls;
}
```

The problem I face now is that on compilation, every line where I use those global window type are now breaking

> src/main.ts:12:1 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Cesium'.

How can I fix this ?  In visual Code, the autocompletion is correct, but on compilation he don't find them.

I also tried

```
import * as Cesium from "cesium";
import * as Hls from "hls.js";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    Cesium: typeof Cesium;
    Hls: typeof Hls;
  }
}
```

but nothing

The file is added to `tsconfig`

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "./src/global.d.ts"],
  }
```

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";
import { environment } from "./environments/environment";

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

// Needed to initialize Cesium
Cesium.buildModuleUrl.setBaseUrl("/assets/cesium/");

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
  },
  "files": ["main.ts", "polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

The type is exported as follow https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cesium/index.d.ts

Comment: Can you show your `main.ts`? And make sure you have that line in `tsconfig.app.json` : `"include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]`

Comment: @David sure let me edit